# issue when trying to split url in js

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I am trying to take token from url.
I am trying this code

```
     const userURL = document.location;
     const shared_token = userURL.split('/')[4].split('?')[0];
     alert(shared_token)
```

my url is something like this:

```
http://www.something.com/earlyAccessPage/%217y%2299%24SYE8FJ7s9oVWix1i6HSC9ega21nXhhOty0UbgrX09jQhssmXMPhXK?fbclid=IwAR2cFvZgJAJsm1zaaRVdb20vzGzZg1qnazTtW-9Bm25DIsiSkdIBEKdjNfo
```

But it's show error: userURL.split is not a function. Please help me to correct my code.

Comment: The `Document.location` read-only property returns a `Location` object. Try `document.location.href` or `document.URL` instead. Read [Document.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location).

Comment: i tried document.URL; const shared_token = userURL.split('/')[4].split('?')[0];
  alert(shared_token); but gettinh error like "const shared_token = userURL.split('/')[4].split('?')[0];
  alert(shared_token)". I need only take token part "%217y%2299%24SYE8FJ7s9oVWix1i6HSC9ega21nXhhOty0UbgrX09jQhssmXMPhXK"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [location.pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) - that can be document.location or window.location - either will work for you: [Location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

```
location.pathname.split("/").pop()
```

returns

```
%217y%2299%24SYE8FJ7s9oVWix1i6HSC9ega21nXhhOty0UbgrX09jQhssmXMPhXK
```

Using your code:

```
const userURL = document.location;
const shared_token = userURL.pathname.split('/').pop(); // take the last part of the  path
alert(shared_token)
```

***NOTE*** In the example I use `new URL()` to make a URL from the URL you provided. You just need `document.location`

```js
// const shared_token= location.pathname.split("/").pop() in your real code
const shared_token= new URL("http://www.something.com/earlyAccessPage/%217y%2299%24SYE8FJ7s9oVWix1i6HSC9ega21nXhhOty0UbgrX09jQhssmXMPhXK?fbclid=IwAR2cFvZgJAJsm1zaaRVdb20vzGzZg1qnazTtW-9Bm25DIsiSkdIBEKdjNfo")
  .pathname
  .split("/")
  .pop()
console.log(shared_token)
```

To get parameters AFTER the ? use

```js
// const url = location
const url = new URL("http://www.something.com/earlyAccessPage/%217y%2299%24SYE8FJ7s9oVWix1i6HSC9ega21nXhhOty0UbgrX09jQhssmXMPhXK?fbclid=IwAR2cFvZgJAJsm1zaaRVdb20vzGzZg1qnazTtW-9Bm25DIsiSkdIBEKdjNfo")

const usp = new URLSearchParams(url.search)

const fbclid = usp.get("fbclid")

console.log(fbclid)
```

Comment: From the code snippet provided in the question description, the `shared_token` is not in the search params

Comment: @Hangindev That is a variable name OP gave it. Please run the code

Comment: I believe the questioner was trying to get "%217y%2299%24SYE8FJ7s9oVWix1i6HSC9ega21nXhhOty0UbgrX09jQhssmXMPhXK" part but not the "fbclid=IwAR2cFvZgJAJsm1zaaRVdb20vzGzZg1qnazTtW-9Bm25DIsiSkdIBEKdjNfo" part.

Comment: can you help me to get only "%217y%2299%24SYE8FJ7s9oVWix1i6HSC9ega21nXhhOty0UbgrX09jQhssmXMPhXK" part?

Comment: @VardanHambardzumyan - I am doing exactly that. See update for explanation - Look in the first example `location.pathname.split("/").pop()`

Comment: I can't understend what I should to write in URL() ...const shared_token= new URL()
  .pathname
  .split("/")
  .pop()
alert(shared_token);

Comment: @VardanHambardzumyan Ok, I explaining in a way you may better understand Please reload the page to see the new information

Comment: const shared_token = new URL(document.location.href)
  .pathname
  .split("/")
  .pop()
console.log(shared_token)
I write this way...but as I am in localhost I can't see my token...you think it will work on production?

Comment: You do NOT NEED the `new URL`, that was for DEMO purposes. You just need `const userURL = document.location;
const shared_token = userURL.pathname.split('/').pop(); 
alert(shared_token)` or shorter: 
`const shared_token = document.location.pathname.split('/').pop(); 
alert(shared_token)`

Answer (score 1):

this is wrong. document.location returns location object. you are try to split location object. so instead of that try to use `const url = document.URL`.

ref : [Document.URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/URL)

```
 const userURL = document.URL;
 const shared_token = userURL.split('/')[4].split('?')[0];
 alert(shared_token)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a Location object back from `document.location` which already splits up the url for you in handy ways. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) for details, but it looks like `userURL.search` would give you what's after the question mark. So your code could simply to:

```js
// if you want the first value after the '?' you can do this:
const search = document.location.search;
const firstSearch = search ? search.substring(1).split("&")[0] : "";

// if you want the value immediately before the '?' you can do this:
const segments = document.location.pathname.split("/");
const lastSegment = segments[segments.length-1];
```

You can always use the original `userURL.href` but see the various parts of `Location` that are already prepared for you (like `host`, `port`, `pathname` and `search`).

Comment: PS: OP is not looking for the search but what is just before the search

Comment: I agree that OP's code was getting the url segment before the '?' but given the variable name "shared_token" I expect they really are wanting what's after the '?'. however I've updated my answer to show getting both values.

Comment: const segments = document.location.pathname.split("/");
const lastSegment = segments[segments.length-1]; I used this code but it return only "earlyAccessPage" I need to get only this part "%217y%2299%24SYE8FJ7s9oVWix1i6HSC9ega21nXhhOty0UbgrX09jQhssmXMPhXK"

Comment: what does `document.location.pathname` give you?

Comment: first code give nothing, second one gives "earlyAccessPage"

Comment: do `console.log(document.location)` to see the full object structure - from there you will see which data has the one you want